How to find all the files and folders with emoji in the name?
I’m trying to upload files to Box. It doesn’t allow files with emoji in the name to be uploaded. I’m on MacOS. So how can I find all the files, and folders, with emoji in the name? So I can begin uploading uninterrupted.
Thank you.

Apparently Box only allows characters from the  Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane. You may have better luck ensuring names have only characters in that range instead of trying to track down all of the emojis.

As Gairfowl says, I would try to find all files with names which contain a character, which is not in the 0x20 ... 0x7A range, i.e. something like find BASEDIR -name '*[^ -z]*', and then rename them. Pray that they aren't plenty!

Thank you! This is exactly what I’m looking for! But it will show filenames with Chinese characters too. Can you help change the command a bit so it won’t include Chinese characters?
